# Typescript inherited property initialized in a function is overwritten

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, create-react-app, next.js

A little bit of background, I'm migrating my source code from Create React App to Next.JS and TypeScript is compiled differently.

Look at this example:

```
abstract class Parent {
  constructor(val: any) {
    this.init(val);
  }

  abstract init(val: any);
}

class Child extends Parent {
  foo: string;

  constructor(val: string) {
    super(val);
  }

  init(val: any) {
    this.foo = val;
  }
}

const i = new Child('test');
console.log(i.foo);
```

I expect `console.log` to print `test` but instead, it prints `undefined` (tried it in TypeScript Playground and works as expected).

The problem is that I'm not sure which config cause this weird behavior, my first suspect was `tsconfig --> strictPropertyInitialization` tried to set it to `false` but nothing changed.

here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "es6",
      "dom",
      "es2015",
      "es2017"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
  }
}
```

Any help will be verymuch appreciated,

Tomer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are targeting ESNext, the JavaScript output will look like the following example, which in a modern browser outputs "test".

```js
class Parent {
    constructor(val) {
        this.init(val);
    }
}
class Child extends Parent {
    constructor(val) {
        super(val);
    }
    init(val) {
        this.foo = val;
    }
}
const i = new Child('test');
console.log(i.foo);
```

If you attempt to run this in an older runtime that doesn't support ECMAScript class syntax, this won't work.

Comment: Are you sure ? I tried in the playground and it appears to work:

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=abstract%20class%20Parent%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(val%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.init(val)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20abstract%20init(val%3A%20any)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Child%20extends%20Parent%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20foo%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor(val%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20super(val)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20init(val%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.foo%20%3D%20val%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20i%20%3D%20new%20Child('test')%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(i.foo)%3B

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - that's kinda what I'm saying. It works on this very page if you hit "Run code snippet" (and aren't using a crazy browser!)

Comment: Oh, my bad, I though you were saying it only works if you target esnext.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - I clean that sentence up a bit to maket clearer!

Comment: Thanks a lot, tried to change it from esnext to es5 (like it used to be with CRA) but nothing changed. The good thing is that you pointed me in the right direction - I found out that this is an open issue with `@babel/plugin-transform-typescript`. (https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9105).